# Can't call angular ng-click from jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-plugins, angularjs-scope

Im trying to call ng-click from jQuery but cant get it work. Can someone tell me how to do it properly?

HTML:

```
<a ng-click="changeData()">Testing</a>
<a ng-click="changeData()">Testing 2</a>
<a ng-click="changeData()">Testing 3</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (checkNav && checkNav()) return;
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        // left
        setCurrent(x,y-1);
        e.preventDefault();
    } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
        // up
        setCurrent(x-1,y);
        e.preventDefault();
    } else if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        // right
        setCurrent(x,y+1);
        e.preventDefault();
    } else if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        // down
        setCurrent(x+1,y);
        e.preventDefault();
    } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {

        $('a[ng-click="changeData()"]')

    }
});
```

**I want it to call same function as ng-click when clicking enter**. It works fine if I have the following code for hrefs when clicking enter:

```
} else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                window.location = current.attr('href');
                e.preventDefault();
            }
```

Thanks!

Comment: [ng-keyup](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeyup) Is something like this what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried but couldnt get it to work. Basically when I click "enter" key, I want the same function to be triggered that's being triggered by ng-click. Do you have some idea what to do perhaps?

Comment: maybe add a scope function and ``ng-keydown="keyDown($event)"``  .. the function would look like this ``$scope.keyDown = function(e) { if(e.keyCode === 13) {e.preventDefault(); $scope.changeData(); } });``

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I need it for an experimental feature. I tried with ng-click="changeData()" but it didn't work either. I didnt get any error in the console either, strange.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean you want something like this. Let me know if this is your intent or not:

index.html

```
<input ng-keyup="keyFn(event=$event)" ngclick="clickFn()">click</input>
```

controller.js

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

        $scope.keyFn = function(event){
          if (event.keyCode && event.keyCode === 13/*enter key*/){
              someFunction();
          }
        };
        $scope.clickFn = function(){
            someFunction();
        }
    });

function someFunction(){
    console.log("event fired");
    //functionality shared between click and `enter` keypress
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this on something else than input field? Like button or href when its focused? Right now it works fine on input field but not something else. Thanks!

Comment: `ng-focus="clickFn()"`

Comment: Thanks Jan! However, when I click on "tab", the focus doesnt change to the input submit. Do you happen to know how I can achieve this?

Comment: These are all things you could have found yourself with a quick google search. F.e "angular bind focus" and "angular trigger focus"

Answer (score 0):

`$('a[ng-click="changeData()"]')` just fetches the element. If you want to trigger a click you need to call `.click()` like so

```
$('a[ng-click="changeData()"]').click();
```

But I prefer thomas' answer that doesn't use jQuery at all, I don't see why you'd need it. Seems completely unnecessary for this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I need it for an experimental feature. I tried with ng-click="changeData()" but it didn't work either. I didnt get any error in the console either, strange.